# Rust borrow checker complaining when calling function in a loop

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have a minimal example of a state machine. Each state needs to grab a reference to some data stored in `deps`. These refs can be `mut` at times. The problem arises in the `run_loop` function. There's no issues unless the I invoke `step` in a loop.

I'm probably missing something fundamental to the borrow checker here.

```
pub struct StateMachine<'a> {
    state: State<'a>,
    deps: Deps,
}

struct SharedData;

struct Deps {
    shared_data: SharedData,
}

enum State<'a> {
    A(A<'a>),
    B(B<'a>),
}

struct B<'a> {
    shared_data: &'a mut SharedData,
}

impl<'a> B<'a> {
    pub fn transition(&self, deps: &'a mut Deps) -> Option<State<'a>> {
        Some(State::A(A {
            shared_data: &deps.shared_data,
        }))
    }

    pub fn run(&mut self, _: &State) {
        // do stuff
    }
}

struct A<'a> {
    shared_data: &'a SharedData,
}

impl<'a> A<'a> {
    pub fn transition(&self, deps: &'a mut Deps) -> Option<State<'a>> {
        Some(State::B(B {
            shared_data: &mut deps.shared_data,
        }))
    }

    pub fn run(&self, _: &State) {
        // do stuff
    }
}

impl<'a> StateMachine<'a> {
    fn run_loop(state_machine: &'a mut StateMachine<'a>) {
        // loop { Doesn't compile when uncommented
            state_machine.step();
        // }
    }

    pub fn step(&'a mut self) {
        let mut state = match &self.state {
            State::A(state) => state.transition(&mut self.deps),
            State::B(state) => state.transition(&mut self.deps),
        }
        .unwrap();

        match &mut state {
            State::A(state) => state.run(&self.state),
            State::B(state) => state.run(&self.state),
        };
        self.state = state;
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if I should not be using lifetimes and opt in for smart pointers here.

Comment: `&'a mut Something<'a>` is nearly always wrong. You need two lifetimes to express this situation.

Comment: Your `StateMachine` type looks self-referential. In particular, the `&'a mut SharedData` nested inside of `state` looks like it's pointing at `deps`. That's a can of worms you probably don't want to get into.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the code is that

```
pub fn step(&'a mut self) {}
```

will keep the reference to `self` for its whole `struct` lifetime, so forever.

You can just remove any lifetime and the self referential pointer and just use pointers to `Deps`.

```
    pub struct StateMachine {
        state: State,
        deps: Deps,
    }
    
    struct SharedData;
    
    struct Deps {
        shared_data: SharedData,
    }
    
    enum State {
        A(A),
        B(B),
    }
    
    struct B {
    }
    
    impl B {
        pub fn transition(&self, deps: &mut Deps) -> Option<State> {
            Some(State::A(A {
            }))
        }
    
        pub fn run(&mut self, _: &State, deps: &mut Deps) {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
    
    struct A {
    }
    
    impl A {
        pub fn transition(&self, deps: &mut Deps) -> Option<State> {
            Some(State::B(B {
            }))
        }
    
        pub fn run(&self, _: &State, deps: &mut Deps) {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
    
    impl StateMachine {
        fn run_loop(state_machine: &mut StateMachine) {
            loop {
                state_machine.step();
            }
        }
    
        pub fn step(&mut self) {
            let mut state = match &self.state {
                State::A(state) => state.transition(&mut self.deps),
                State::B(state) => state.transition(&mut self.deps),
            }
                .unwrap();
    
            match &mut state {
                State::A(state) => state.run(&self.state, &mut self.deps),
                State::B(state) => state.run(&self.state, &mut self.deps),
            };
            self.state = state;
        }
    }
    
    fn main() {}
```